# Inserir porcentagem na barra de progresso (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Fiz uma barra de progresso com o bootstrap. Aí cada vez que algo é preenchido na tabela uma certa porcentagem a mais é inserido na barra. Os dados que são inseridos na tabela vêm de uma API, então ela faz isso automaticamente. Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
function Progresso(){
  var progressTest = document.querySelector('.info-nome');

  var teste = progressTest.textContent || progressTest.innerText;

  var cont = teste.length;

  if (cont > 0) {
    var Porc = document.getElementById('progresso_Id').style.width = "5%";
  }
}
```

Se caso a classe que vem da api que contem o nome for preenchida, ou seja, for mais que 0, vai inserir 5% na barra de progresso. Mas infelizmente não funciona como eu quero. Outro exemplo do resto do meu código:

```
function Prog() {

  var progressTest = document.querySelector('.info-cpf');

  var teste = progressTest.textContent || progressTest.innerText;

  var cont = teste.length;

  if (cont > 0) {
    var Porc = document.getElementById('progresso_Id').style.width = "10%";
  }
}
```

Ou seja, ele não ta acrescentando +5%, e sim logo 10%, então se o nome não for inserido e o cpf sim, ele já vai pra 10%

Como eu faço para ser inserido +5% e nao já mudar o width da barra de progresso?
**A barra de progresso é pelo bootstrap**

```
    <div class="container conteudo">
  <div class="row nospace">

            <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger active progress-bar-striped progresso" id="progresso_Id" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
            <span class="sr-only">0%</span>
          </div>
            </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

**E tem como fazer isso em javascript puro?**
*Se possível, também gostaria de saber como coloco pra mostrar quanto por cento já tem na barra para o usuário ver*

API:

```
    var endereco = `http://api`;

$.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    crossDomain: true,
    complete: function(res){
        var meuJSON = JSON.parse(res.responseText);

        var a = [meuJSON];

        a.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              element[i]
              var adiciona = element;

AdicionaNome(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaCPF(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaProduto(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaCidade(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaCodigoProduto(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaCodigoCliente(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaStatus(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaEntPrevista(adiciona[1]);
AdicionaEntregaProgramada(adiciona[1]);
```

Comment: A variável `teste.length` retorna os valores de 0-100? Você pode criar uma variável para armazenar o valor e depois mais somando 5 + 5.

Comment: teste.length retorna a quantidade de caracteres que tem no dado da classe

Comment: @maria coloca os inputs do html

Comment: @JulioHenrique Não tem nenhum input do html

Comment: Os dados da API que você mencionou, vem em forma de JSON ou a própria **API** renderiza o HTML? Não consegui entender

Comment: @MatheusCuba eu formato ela em JSON, aí crio uma td pelo js para inserir elas. Vou colocar na pergunta a forma q mexo no API

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, não é uma boa ideia deixar o valor para ser adicionado fixo no Código. Você pode simplesmente contar os campos e dividir por `100`, te dando a quantia em `%` equivalente.

Depois, você pode criar uma Array com os campos que precisa contabilizar (o nome das classes que você usar em `.info-*`) e chamar a função que eu coloquei no Snippet

**Tudo** em JavaScript puro

```js
//Campos que deseja contabilizar
var listaCampos = ["cpf", "nome", "idade", "endereco"];

//Elemento da Barra de Progresso
var barraProgresso = document.getElementById("barra");
function Progresso(){
   var total = 0;
   
   //% equivalente a cada campo
   var count = 100/(listaCampos.length);
   for(var i in listaCampos){
      var campo = listaCampos[i]; 
      
      //Verifica se campo Existe
      var campoEncontrado = document.querySelector('.info-' + campo);    
      if(campoEncontrado){ 
          //Soma Porcentagem equivalente ao Total
          total += count;
      }
   }
   
   //Seta Propriedades da Barra de Progresso
   barraProgresso.style.width = total + "%";
   barraProgresso.innerHTML = total + "%";
}


//Funções apenas para Demonstração do Código

var pessoa = { nome: "João Silva", cpf: "123.123.123-00", endereco : "Visconde de Pelotas", idade: 32 };
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

function InserirCampo(prop){
    var elemento = document.createElement('span');
    elemento.className = "info-"+prop;
    elemento.innerHTML = pessoa[prop];
    resultado.appendChild(elemento);
    Progresso();
}
```

```css
span{
   margin: 10px;
}

.progress{
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button onclick="InserirCampo('nome')">Inserir Nome</button>
<button onclick="InserirCampo('cpf')">Inserir CPF</button>
<button onclick="InserirCampo('endereco')">Inserir Endereço</button>
<button onclick="InserirCampo('idade')">Inserir Idade</button>

<div id="resultado"></div>


<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" id="barra"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0">
    0%
  </div>
</div>
```